# Platform invoke #define directive

Tags: c#, c++, c, pinvoke

I am trying to understand platform invokes. So, i understood many concepts but how can i invoke `#define` directives in c#.

Example:

in C++ side i have this:

```
#define dont_care_how_you_invoke_me (ptr)
```

I've tried this:

```
[DllImport("mydll.dll")]
static extern void dont_care_how_you_invoke_me(IntPtr ptr);
```

This didn't work. I've searched on google for a while and couldn't find anything so i'm not even sure if this is possible or not.

Thanks in advance

Comment: As c# doesn't have a preprocessor you can't.

Comment: Why would you want to "invoke" preprocessor macros? These things are expanded during compilation and thus don't even exist in the resulting executable, much like inline functions, except that they lack type safety and a few other things. Neither can be called from C# because well, they're not really functions, they're just a bunch of instructions inserted at the location where the function call was located. Just use regular functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PInvoke imported methods in C# correspond to actual **exported** functions in a DLL, not the C/C++ syntactical representation of a function (which is why you use name-mangling when dealing with member functions in C++)

Instead of using the C/C++ header file as a reference for functions, use a tool to see what functions are being exported from a DLL and use those names directly.

A good tool for this is Dependency Walker: http://www.dependencywalker.com/